# Vulkan: Unable to render using multiple view ports

Tags: rendering, camera, vulkan

I have been trying to enable multiple viewports in my Vulkan Pipeline but have been unsucsessfull. I used this [code sample](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/viewportarray/viewportarray.cpp) as a reference point. The problem is that when I attempt to draw two side by side (splitscreen) views of a scene I am unsuccessful.

Pipeline Initialisation

```
// Viewport state
VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewport_state = initializers::PipelineViewportStateCreateInfo(CameraComponent::GetCameraCount(), CameraComponent::GetCameraCount());

// Dynamic shader stages
std::vector<VkDynamicState> dynamic_states = {
    VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
    VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR,
    VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH,
};
VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamic_states_info = initializers::PipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo(dynamic_states);
```

(Using the debuger shows that CameraComponent::GetCameraCount() is 2)

Command Buffer

```
vkCmdSetViewport(cmd, 0, CameraComponent::GetCameraCount(), CameraComponent::GetViewports());
vkCmdSetScissor(cmd, 0, CameraComponent::GetCameraCount(), CameraComponent::GetScissors());
```

(Here CameraComponent::GetCameraCount() is 2 aswell as the viewport and scissor methods returning valid data)

When Using Nvidia NSight we can see that both Scissors and Viewports are detected
[image]

As well as there position data existing within the gpu
[image]

But when it comes to the result, all that is visible is half of the screen. 
[image]
When I flip the cameras around within the code, the second half is rendered instead showing that the first camera is being rendered but not the second one.

Comment: You should really post a complete example.  What does your geometry shader look like?  Are you doing this to try to implement stereo rendering?  If so, you might want to use the VK_KHR_MULTIVIEW extension (core in Vulkan 1.1) instead of viewport arrays, since it requires no geometry shader work.

Comment: I've not added a geometry shader to this, I did not know it was a requirement for it to work. I will look into the geometry shader now as well as VK_KHR_MULTIVIEW

Comment: ["A geometry shader is used to output geometry to multiple viewports in one single pass"](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/viewportarray/viewportarray.cpp#L277)

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: Line 277 of the Sascha Willems example you linked to in your question.  Also, it's a link to the line in question.